# Transparent window application to overlay in Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to write an application to process certain user actions.

The application will be always transparent and should be click through. So, the window behind will be seen and as the transparent application is click through I should be able to click on the window behind. Only certain user actions(like double click) I want to handle in my transparent application.

Is it possible to achieve this? Any guidelines are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make fake window click from your app:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

private void Form_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   Point p = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN , p.X, p.Y, 0, 0);
   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, p.X, p.Y, 0, 0);
   this.Show();//since this.opacity = 0; form will never be really visible
}
```

Now on double click you can set what ever you want.

Comment: How would you go about making sure that this fake form is on top? When the user brings some other form to the top of the z-order, this form will not receive the double click.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-yes, that is a problem indeed.

Comment: @Amen What about the other top most windows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , jimmy sad he want it for presentation, so i think he will not run task manager and challenge his own app :), and we can setup a 1 second timer refreshing topmost property

Answer (score 1):

You can make a window that is transparent and click through. However, it's all or nothing. You can't be click through apart from double clicks.

So, to do what you want I believe you will need to use a global mouse hook to handle the double clicks. But that's going to require native code.

In fact, come to think of it, why do you need the transparent click through window at all?

Comment: when doing presentations or training that could give the ability to enhance the experiece. For example I could underline/circle a part of the application/presentaion I am showing.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have the ability to extend the functionality. I haven't seen any open source utility which I can extend.